# Netbeans configure the Java Platform classpath

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

I'm developing a Netbeans plugin and I have the following problem trying to use the Java library tools.jar.

- Tools.jar is locate in the folder ..\jdk8\lib
- Netbeans is configured to use the Java platform in the folder ..\jdk8
- If I check the list of Java libraries that Netbeans uses I can see that all are taken from the folder ..\jdk8\jre\lib and NOT from ..\jdk8\lib .

How can I configure Netbeans to load also the libraries in that other folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add a custom library from Tools ==> Libraries ==> commonlib and manually add its path of jar files to your project.
2. Netbean uses ant that is XML script and execute build process. You can modify build.xml to set it according to your requirements

Thanks

Comment: Hi I know those procedures, but actually what I want is to load the library into the classpath of Netbeans itself and not into the project on which I'm working. Thanks in any case for the answer.

Comment: Then unzip and place the folder that jar contains to your classpath. This will work

Comment: please vote up or mark answer if this helped you in any case. This pleased me to go a head and work more actively in this community